# Re-enable javascript dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I am rewriting this question because I think it deserves to be answered.  The reason given for why it was closed is as follows: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself."

The specific problem: When calling too many alerts/confirms in JavaScript (as might happen from a bug in your code), the browser will eventually ask you if you want to ignore further alerts.  Once you ignore these alerts, how do you get the browser to re-enable those alerts?

Valid code to reproduce the problem:

```
<script>while(true) alert("Stop Me");</script>
```

I'll go on to answer the question if it's re-opened...

Here is Zane's original question:

When developing in javascript, I sometimes will end up in a situation where I generate alerts
in an endless loop. Silly but true.

To get out of this endless loop, I either need to close the browser (normally using chrome) or disable dialogs for the page. But I don't know how to re-enable dialogs without restarting browser.

Is there a simple way to re-enable the dialogs? Surprisingly, I didn't get anything useful when googling for it.

Zane

Comment: Instead of using `alert` why don't you use `console.log`?

Comment: More like a superuser question as its about software.

Comment: Oh my, you guys are being too harsh.  This is a legit question and I wish I'd found the answer here, but I shall keep searching...

Comment: @Danger: thanks. Taking rules too literally is not always beneficial. I hope it's now easier for everybody to google for this. And I promise to include code in my next question.

Comment: @Thew: hm, and looking at this again : my question was about javascript. Hard to draw the line between language, library and interpreter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Close tab > Ctrl+Shift+T (reopen last closed tab)

Works every time.

Comment: I was just about to say "no" as I thought I had tried that. But it looks as if you're right. Thanks.

Comment: Cmd+Shift+T for Chrome @ MacOX

Answer (score 4):

Let me present an alternative answer from what you're asking, as I think `alerts()` are a rather time consuming way to debug, *especially* when you're using Chrome as your development platform.

Developing with the aid of various [console functions](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api) you can get a more streamlined debugging workflow set into place.

I understand that `alerts()` are sometimes good to stop the execution to read your code - although console has commands to cater for this as well:

### debugger;

```
for( var x = 0; x < 10; x++ ) {
   if ( x == 5 ) 
       debugger;  //Console opens, press F8 to resume or F10 to step into.
}
```

[image]

### Console.warn and Console.log

```
   for( var y = 10; y > 0; y-- ) {
      if ( y == 4 ) 
         console.warn( 'Oh no!', y );
      else
         console.log( 'Normal:', y );
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Not really the answer to my question, but this will probably save me more time. Thanks.